# Creating exe for my java Application in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my java program to an .exe file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

hi folks,

how to create the exe file of my application in eclipse? please mention the steps to follow.

Thanks

Comment: See [How can I convert my java program to an .exe file ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're just wondering how to run your application outside the Eclipse IDE, then you don't need an exe. Look for the "Export JAR" option in the menu.

If the export is done properly (with a MANIFEST generated), you should then be able to run the JAR file by double-clicking on it, or from the commandline with "java -jar FILENAME.jar". Note that this is a platform-independent format.

Answer (score 7):

Launch4J:You can use Launch4J application to covert jar to exe.

Steps:
1) Create .jar file for your application using your IDE with proper MANIFEST.
2) Run Launch4j and convert .jar to .exe