# Deploying console in java

Tags: java, deployment, console

I know with programming languages like VB that their console applications are made in exe to run. I want to know if/how to deploy a console app in java.

Re: Can you make a .jar file for java console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows .exe (standalone executable) using Java/Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719376/how-can-i-create-a-windows-exe-standalone-executable-using-java-eclipse)

Comment: I want to deploy a console app not a built panel/frame (gui).

Comment: How will you run the app ? If it's a console application, it will open the console automatically. Or just run it using a batch file.

Comment: You can run the jar from command line and the console should output there.

Comment: @Compass ok, so if i execute the jar from command line the output will be in like comand prompt console?

Comment: @Timmi Yes.  Java has built-in classes to handle standard console/command-line input and output.  You don't have to do anything special, you can just read/write from/to System.in/System.out

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks!