# This App Can't Run On Your PC, error when trying to run a JavaFX app from Right Click Menu option

Tags: windows, javafx, registry, windows-security

Running Windows 11

I created a JavaFX Jar. The App/Jar works fine when you double click it, or even execute it from the command prompt.

To make it easier to use, I decided to add an option to my Right Click Options. Following the instruction from here: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors.
I created a registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\MyApp\command
```

This menu option shows up. But when I attempt to click on it. It gives me the error: "This App Can't Run On Your PC"
[image: Error Message]

Again, the app runs fine if executed any other way. I even played around with the menu option to have it run other programs like the command prompt. Which works fine. I can use that menu option to open other programs. But when I try to run my jar file it throws that error.
I'm thinking it's a security issue, but I don't want to go punching holes in my security settings.

Comment: Perhaps if you [make it an exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811401/how-to-create-a-standalone-exe-in-java-that-runs-without-an-installer-and-a-jr/69824145#69824145), or use jpackage to create an installer, it will run more reliably on other systems, and it will be easier to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution.
I created a batch file that calls the JAR.
Then updated the registry key to run the batch file.

Not as elegant as I had hoped and an extra step. But it works.