# Created .exe from jpackager crashes

Tags: java, javafx, jlink, jpackage

I have a JavaFX Project, which I want to export as a dmg and exe. The export as a dmg file for Mac was no problem.
But the export as a .exe file for Windows is not working.
I created a jar file and I ran jlink. Then I exported the project with jpackage.
Here is the command:

```
/path/to/jpackage \
--input %PATH_TO_SDK%/lib/  \
--name "My Project" \
--main-jar /path/to/jar.jar \
--main-class com.company.project.Main \
--type exe \
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics \
--module-path %PATH_TO_SDK%/lib/
```

On my machine, it is working perfect, but on others (I tested it on two more machines (they do not have Java(FX) installed)) the CMD window crashes instantly.

Comment: What if you get rid of the `--input %PATH_TO_SDK%/lib` bit? Also, if that doesn't work, you can try making it a console application (I think the command is something like `--win-console`), run the EXE from the command line, and look at the error output (you may have to tell the terminal to wait, depending on how exactly you launch the program; e.g., with PowerShell, you could use `-NoNewWindow -Wait`). What is the error?

Comment: Now it is not running on my machine as well. I can see a small window (i think not a cmd) for less than a second. When I get rid of the `--input` I get `Error: Missing argument: --input or --app-image`. No error in PowerShell.

Comment: Try running directly from the jlink’d image tree, instead of the packaged .exe.  The image tree will have a command-line executable in its ‘bin’ directory.

Comment: Yes. The ‘Launcher.bat‘ is working on every machine without any error.

Comment: Ok. Finally some progress. Now I can start the application. But I get this error: "Child process exited with code 1". The reason because it crashed yesterday is because I used the IntelliJ Java libs...

Comment: Yes. Finally output in the terminal `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demo.HelloApplication`. That is interesting, baucause the path to the class is correct.

Comment: That does not match the main class name in your question.

Comment: I created a new demo Project for testing. But also this error I was able to solve. Now I have this one (Jeez): `Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found`

Comment: So, there was a problem with jmods. But now I have the same issue like at the beginning. It is working on my machine. And on others I only see 'ClassNotFoundException'.

Comment: I don’t know what your exact issue is, bug you could see this question on [JavaFX exe files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811401/how-to-create-a-standalone-exe-in-java-that-runs-without-an-installer-and-a-jr), specifically the part mentioning the ackman jpackage plugin, though to adapt your project to use it will take some work fir you.  Also see [package info in the JavaFX tag like JPackageScriptFX.

Comment: All this stuff is only working on my computer on one account. I created a new user on my mac, even the new user can't open the dmg :-(  (I have the problem on Mac as well). Thanks for all your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found a GitHub repo which shows how to create dmg and exe files. [Maven jPackage Template](https://github.com/wiverson/maven-jpackage-template)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).